# Python Chess Implementation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm beginning work on a chess implementation and before going too far down the rabbit hole, I wanted to get the community's input if you wouldn't mind since I'm already at a dead end ha. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to associate the pieces with the coordinates.

Right now, I have a list of list with the various pieces where each list represents a board.

For the coordinates, I used this list comprehension

```
coordinates = [[(i,j) for i in range(0,8)] for j in range(0,8)]
```

which gives me a table like this

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), (7, 2)]
[(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3)]
[(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), (7, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5)]
[(0, 6), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), (7, 6)]
[(0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 7)]
```

Any strong thoughts on how I can associate the piece with their coordinate to find potential moves? I was thinking dictionary at first, but you have multiple pieces of the same type (eg. two knights) and don't think this would be ideal as the board evolved.

Thanks as always.

Comment: you can create a dictionary. Each pair is associated to some piece, or nothing. How you represent a piece or nothing : for example, you can maybe go with another tuple like (color/piece)

Comment: However, I find it simpler to create a 2d-array. Each value of the array is a piece (like the tuple I described, for example). Using tuples to represent coordinated of a grid does not seem very practical, IMHO. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878881/python-tuples-dictionaries-as-keys-select-sort

Comment: Will lean on your expertise and go with your suggestion since I'm mostly flying blind. I'm just thinking through your comment. Your suggestion, if I understand correctly, would be to have a 2d array where it is just the game board and the pieces could be described by various letters with upper and lower case describing the side (ie. ignore the coordinates and operate within the list of lists so it is treated as a 2d array)?

Comment: Yes about using the array indices for the coordinates of the board. What you describe about the piece representation as a single letter is more [Joe Iddon's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46736283/479251), and has the benefit of being simple and easily printable. I think it's a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, I have just been working on exactly this! Previously, I wrote [a chess AI](http://joeiddon.me/ChessAI/) but in *javascript*, however today I have been converting that code into Python for use with a bigger project so the knowledge is fresh in my mind.

Originally, in the JS version, I stored the `board` effectively as an `8x8` `array` of `strings` for each piece (in reality this was inside an object with other data such as castling but that is not important).

However, this method of using an `array` (`list` in Python) led to problems due to the way they are passed by `reference`. The issue was that passing the *board state* through the `negamax` algorithm meant that for each `move` to be considered, the whole `array` (in JS) would have to be **copied** to stop the `move` being made to the original board state.

I got around this by storing the board states as `strings` which are `immutable` in Python. I would advise you to start off using `lists` though as they are much simpler to access and change values even though they will probably end up leading to slowness (from making copies of them) later down the line when you come to optimising.

The actual trick to storing the `board` state is to use one `character` for each piece and use `upper` and `lowercase` to represent the `white` and `black` sides. I stole this technique from the widely used [`FEN notation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) and it turns out to be really useful for both `displaying` and doing `operations` on the board *state*!

To see what I mean, you could initialise the starting state with:

```
state = ["RNBQKBNR", "PPPPPPPP", "        ", "        ", "        ", "        ", "pppppppp", "rnbqkbnr"]
state = [list(r) for r in state]
```

and then you can easily create a `display` function with:

```
def display(state):
   for r in reversed(state):
      print(''.join(r))
```

then whenever you want to display a given state, you can call `display(state)` which gives:

```
rnbqkbnr
pppppppp




PPPPPPPP
RNBQKBNR
```

Hopefully this helps you out! You can look at the code for my full implementation of a chess AI on `github`: [in Python](https://github.com/RoadKillCat/ChessRobot/blob/master/intelligence.py) and [in javascript](https://github.com/roadkillcat/ChessAI/) **:)**

Answer (score 1):

OK it goes like this:
You got 64 cells, traditionally coordinated with letter and digit.
Name each cell numeric so that cell will coordinated: "a1" will be 11, h5 will be 85 etc.

Now for the moves:

1. Up:  (cell value) + 1, Down: (cell value) - 1, Right: (cell value) +
   10, Left: (cell value) - 10,
2. Diagnose:    Up-Left: (cell value) - 9,   Up-Right: (cell value) +
   11,   Down-Left: (cell value) - 11,   Down-Right: ((cell value) + 9,
3. And for the Knight: (cell value) + 21, (cell value) - 21, (cell
   value) + 12, (cell value) - 12, (cell value) + 8, (cell value) - 8,
   (cell value) + 19, (cell value) – 19.

As you can understand, I recently build one by myself ( based on JS if you mind) ha ha.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, the most obvious simple implementation is a list of lists, for example in my implementation this logic creates the board, and then pieces are added to it using the `add()` method:

https://github.com/akulakov/pychess/blob/7176b168568000af721e79887981bcd6467cfbc0/chess.py#L141